# calculate rotation matrix from 4 points

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I would like to stick a moving car to a curvy terrarian. I can calculate the y coordinate (which is height in my case) for each wheel. These 4 points forms a plane. I don't know how to calculate the rotation matrix from these 4 pints so I can apply it to the car. So this is what I would like to achieve:

calculateRotationMatrix(p1,p2,p3,p4);

BTW I am using c++ and openGL.

Could anybody help me out here?

Comment: Did your code that does this run into a problem, or do you want a mathematical formula for this?

Comment: 4 points don't necessarily have to lie on a plane.

Comment: If the car rolls over, there would only be one point.

Comment: My car does no roll over it just sticks to the surface. derhass you are right 4 point does not have to lie on a plane but I don't wanna crack the car into half XD. So I will use the 3 heaviest point to create a tri and then just calculate the 4th coordinate to create a plane which surly lie on a plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you guarantee that all 4 points lie on one plane, then the problem is not that hard to solve: Let's call the points (A,B,C,D) and we define a up vector (UP = [0,1,0])

1) Calculate the plane normal (N)

```
N = normalize(cross(B-A, C-A));
```

2) Calculate the rotation axis (R)

```
R = normalize(cross(N,UP))
```

3) Calculate rotation angle (alpha)

```
alpha = dot(N, UP)
```

The resulting matrix is then the one that rotates around R by an angle of alpha. If your matrix library does not support creating rotation axis around arbitrary axis, you can find the form [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations).

Note, that there is a singularity when alpha is very small (N will then vanish), so you should only calculate the matrix if alpha is sufficiently large. It might also be that case that some of the vectors point to the opposite direction depending on the winding order in which the points are defined. In this case just switch the two parameters of the cross function.

Comment: Actually you don't even have to do the dot product and product a rotation matrix from that. All you need is the cross product to obtain a vector orthogonal to the plane. You already have the plane base vectors B-A and C-A, which form two legs of a tripod. Use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization; the resulting three vectors *are* the desired rotation matrix, you just have put them side by side.